# Imagemagick C++ api conversion from svg to png not using custom fonts

Tags: c++, ubuntu, svg, imagemagick, png

I am using the ImageMagick C++ api to convert from SVG to PNG. The SVG has a .css file and .ttf fonts are in the input data.

If I add the fonts to the `~/.fonts` folder and use the fc-cache command, my conversion works fine. The conversion also works fine if I use already-installed-fonts on my system.

The problem is that I cannot adjust any configuration on the server where it will be running, so i was looking for a runtime solution.
Using fc-cache to point at the directory where the fonts are didn't work for me.
I found the MAGICK_FONT_PATH environment variable and I created a type.xml in the input data fonts folder. Then I pointed the MAGICK_FONT_PATH to the type.xml folder, and when I list fonts with `convert -list font` I can see the fonts, but using the imageMagick api directly from C++ doesn't use the fonts.

The code is something like:

```
magickImage.write(&blob);
```

Does anyone know how to use custom fonts with the imagemagick api? Where the fonts-to-be-used are defined in the .css file?

Comment: convert the fonts into data URIs and embed them in the svg files.

Comment: Are you invoking `Magick::InitializeMagick` at the start of the C++ application do load the configuration environment?

Comment: I found a solution. I now use the environment variable XDG_CONFIG_HOME to point it at a folder which then contains fontconfig/fonts.conf. That fonts.conf then can point at the custom fonts folder, without having to install them. And imagemagick doesn't use .css files at all, so now using code that copies that replaces the css classes in the svg file with the actual contents of the css class.